# SimpleXML Getting raw value of element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have following XML code and I *have* to use SimpleXML:

```
<CATEGORY_TREE>/Gry&#47;Puzzle/puzzle/</CATEGORY_TREE>
<CATEGORY_NAME>/Gry&#47;Puzzle/puzzle/</CATEGORY_NAME>
```

`$node->CATEGORY_TREE` returns `/Gry/Puzzle/puzzle/` which is correct.

Any way to get raw value `/Gry&#47;Puzzle/puzzle/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by not using an LibXML2 based XML parser (SimpleXML, DOM, XMLReader). They all force the replacement of the predefined entities.

From the [LibXML2 documentation](http://www.xmlsoft.org/entities.html):

> Note that at save time libxml2 enforces the conversion of the
>   predefined entities where necessary to prevent well-formedness
>   problems, and will also transparently replace those with chars (i.e.
>   it will not generate entity reference elements in the DOM tree or call
>   the reference() SAX callback when finding them in the input).

For the XML parser '/' and '+' are equal. To store the entity in XML its `&` would have to be escaped. If you create it as a text node in DOM you will see that DOM will do it for the serialization:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('CATEGORY_TREE'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('/Gry&#47;Puzzle/puzzle/'));
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CATEGORY_TREE>/Gry&amp;#47;Puzzle/puzzle/</CATEGORY_TREE>
```

Comment: I think i forgot to mention, I'm parsing XML, not creating it.

Comment: I understood that, but for an XML parser `/` and `&#43;` are the same. so `/Gry/Puzzle/puzzle/` IS the raw value (at least for libxml2 based XML parsers). If you want to read `&#43;` as the entity the  best solution would be that the program/script encodes the entity. Otherwise you will have to use an XML parser that does not substitute the predefined entities by default or string functions (aka write your own parser). Be prepared for other problems in this case. Here are reasons that LibXML2 substitutes them.

Answer (score -1):

use html_entity_decode() function:

```
<?php
echo html_entity_decode($node->CATEGORY_TREE);
```